# ¿Cómo pasar las variables a una plantilla llamada por medio de .load jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

El sistema funciona de la siguiente manera, se está implementando el sistema de carrito con multi proceso utilizando un `script` de `wizard js`.

Todo los pasos del proceso `wizard`, se visualizan en la misma página `cart.php` sin recargar o refrescar la página, los datos son visualizados correctamente.

Anteriormente tenía un problema en la plantilla que se llama por medio de un `.load jQuery`, al `cart.php`, en la plantilla **pay_paypal.php** solo había puesto las variables que esta ya existen globalmente en el archivo **cart.php** pero realmente estaba equivocado del funcionamiento del `.load`, el `.load` trae los resultados actuales el que se encuentra en el archivo

**pay_paypal.php**

```
<form name='pay' id="payment" method='post' action='https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'>
  <input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_cart">
  <input name="upload" type="hidden" value="1">
  <input name="business" type="hidden" value="jdoew21@hotmail.com">
  <input name="shopping_url" type="hidden" value="http://localhost/mitienda/productos.php">
  <input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="EUR">
  <input name="return" type="hidden" value="http://localhost/mitienda/exito.php">
  <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://localhost/mitienda/exito.php'>
  <input name="notify_url" type="hidden" value="http://localhost/mitienda/paypalipn.php">
  <input name="rm" type="hidden" value="2">

<?php
  while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $key = array_search($id_pro, $items);
    $total = $total + $price * $qty[$key];
?>
  <input name="item_number_<?php echo $num;?>" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_pro; ?>">
  <input name="item_name_<?php echo $num;?>" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $product; ?>">
  <input name="amount_<?php echo $num;?>" type="hidden" value="<?php echo number_format($price,2);?>">
  <input name="quantity_<?php echo $num;?>" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $qty[$key];?>">
<?php
  $num++;
  }
?>

</form>
```

Y por lo tanto esto me generaba por cada una de las variables el mismo error, al traer el archivo de tal manera.

> Notice: Undefined variable: id_product in C:\xampp\htdocs...\templante\app\pay_paypal.php on line 13

El error lo solucioné, añadiendo en el archivo **pay_paypal.com** lo mismos datos que existen en el archivo **cart.php** realmente algo extenso tener que hacerlo de tal manera, el mismo procedimiento me tocara realizarlo en las otras plantillas de pago.

Mi pregunta entonces es, si se puede enviar por medio de `ajax` las variables al seleccionar el `input radio` que llama la plantilla en un `<div id="divPago"></div>` por medio de `.load jquery`

```
<?php
$r =array(
    1 => 'Transferencia Bancaria',
    2 => 'PayPal',
    3 => 'Tarjeta de credito',
);
?>
<div class="group-radio">
  <?php
     foreach ($r as $key => $value) :
  ?>
  <input name="radio" type="radio" id="<?php echo $key ?>" value="<?php echo $key ?>" <?php echo ($radio == $key ? 'checked="checked"' : ''); ?> >
  <label for="<?php echo $key ?>" title="<?php echo $value ?>"><?php echo $value ?></label>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Y traer como respuesta los resultados deseados, para evitar tener que añadir todos los mismo datos que se encuentran en el archivo **cart.php** a las plantillas de pago llamadas por `.load`.

**Mi script js**

```
function show_step(step){
  var data = $( "#form" ).serialize();
  var url = 'saveTemp.php?step=' + step;
  // recuperamos el lavel del radio button seleccionado
  //var valor_radio = $('input:radio[name=radio]:checked').next("label").text();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data
  }).done(function(resp){

    step = parseInt(step);
    $('#address').val(resp.address);
    $('#email').val(resp.email);
    $('#name').val(resp.name);
    $('#phone').val(resp.phone);
    $('#radio').val(resp.radio);
    $('#username').val(resp.username);

    if (step === 2) {
       var radio = parseInt(resp.radio);
       switch(radio) {
          case 1:
            urlform = './app/themes/pay_paypal.php'
          break;
          case 2:
            urlform = './app/themes/pay_paypal2.php'
          break;
          case 3:
            urlform = './app/themes/pay_paypal3.php'
          break;
          default:
            urlform = './app/themes/pay_paypal4.php'
          break;

        }
      $('#divPago').load(urlform,function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
        if(statusTxt === "success") {
          $('.step').css( "display", "none" );
          $('#step'+ step).fadeIn("slow");
          animacion(step);
        }
        if(statusTxt === "error") {
          //
        }

      });
    } else {
      $('.step').css( "display", "none" );
      $('#step'+ step).fadeIn("slow");
      animacion(step);
    }

  });

};

$(function() {
  show_step(step);
});
```

Comment: ¿Qué variables quieres pasar con el `.load`?

Comment: Doe lo que yo no termino de entender es **dónde están las variables** que tú quieres pasar: `$id_pro, $product, $price, $qty`? No las veo en `cart.php`, no las veo en ninguna parte... ¿dónde pues están esas variables?

Comment: Y no sólo que no estén, es que tendrían el mismo valor para todos los input hidden porque no hay nada en el bucle que las cambie, por lo que deberían ser iguales para todos los campos ocultos

Comment: Doe, si he entendido bien, lo que tú quieres **actualmente** es pasar estas variables `$id_pro, $product, $price, $qty` del archivo `cart.php` a cualquiera de los archivos `pay_paypal.php` para trabajar con ellas allí... ¿estoy entendiendo bien? Si es así, debes mostrar de dónde se deberán tomar esas variables en el archivo `cart.php`, si de un input del formulario o de donde.

Comment: Bueno Doe, ya nos vamos entendiendo. O sea que esas variables son `inputs` que se van agregando según la cantidad de productos que se compren en `cart.php`. Entonces, yo no crearía esas variables como variables globales. Más bien tendría un formulario en `cart.php`  donde se van a agregar todos los productos comprados y luego yo serializo ese formulario y lo mando en la petición Ajax con todos los datos. Pero al decirme eso, ahora no comprendo qué es lo que haces en los archivos `paypal.php`... yo veo que abres un `while` para recorrerlo y hacer unos cálculos y que tratas de presentar inputs.

Comment: Ya Doe. Yo lo que quiero saber es de donde salen los valores que tú quieres manejar. Lo lógico es que estén en `cart.php` y que de allí tú los pases con la petición Ajax al archivo que deberá ejecutarse según lo que se cumpla en el `switch`.

Comment: Doe a mi hay algo que no me cuadra para nada en la lógica que intentas seguir: tú tienes tus variables en `cart.php` ¿cierto?, y luego ¿esas variables tú las mandas a `pay_paypal.php`  o a cualquiera de los otros archivos para presentarlas en inputs y devolverlas de nuevo a `cart.php`? Eso no tiene ninguna utilidad. Generalmente uno manda algo al servidor para en base a esos datos buscar otros. Por ejemplo tú mandas un `id` para que en la base de datos te busque todos los registros relacionados con él... pero aquí parece que estás mandando los datos para no hacer nada con ellos... ¿?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si vas a la [documentación de jQuery para `.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), verás que hay varias maneras diferentes de llamar a la función:

```
.load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )
```

Ahora mismo en tu llamada estás definiendo la `url` (obligatorio) y la función a ejecutar `complete` (opcional):

```
  $('#divPago').load(urlform,function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
    if(statusTxt === "success") {
      $('.step').css( "display", "none" );
      $('#step'+ step).fadeIn("slow");
      animacion(step);
    }
    if(statusTxt === "error") {
      //
    }

  });
```

Pero como puedes ver, puedes mandar otro parámetro: `data` (también opcional) que serían las variables que le quieras pasar a la URL, y que se mandan al servidor en la petición.

Entonces lo que podrías hacer es poner esas variables en un objeto o cadena y pasarlas con el `.load()`. Por ejemplo, asumiendo que los valores de `$num`, `$id_pro` y `$product` se guardaron en campos con esos nombres (sin el símbolo de $):

```
  var num = $("[name=num]").val();
  var id_pro = $("[name=id_pro]").val();
  var product = $("[name=product]").val();

  var datos_a_pasar = {
     num: num, 
     id_pro: id_pro,
     product: product
  }

  $('#divPago').load(urlform, datos_a_pasar, function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
    if(statusTxt === "success") {
      $('.step').css( "display", "none" );
      $('#step'+ step).fadeIn("slow");
      animacion(step);
    }
    if(statusTxt === "error") {
      //
    }

  });
```

Y luego, desde el archivo de destino pay_paypal.php, puedes leer los datos pasados en el `$_REQUEST` o el `$_POST` desde PHP. Por ejemplo

```
$num = $_REQUEST["num"];
$id_pro = $_REQUEST["id_pro"];
$product = $_REQUEST["product"];
```

Comment: Muy claro el ejemplo, solo una duda, en el archivo pay_paypal.php que se debe añadir realizando ya este procedimiento.

Comment: @J.Doe He actualizado la respuesta para adaptarla algo mejor a los campos que mencionas en el comentario. Dime si tienes alguna pregunta.

Comment: Sí, la última pregunta,  en mi archivo **pay_paypal.php** de mi pregunta Ud puede observar que el `while` hace que genere los campos `input` con los datos de paypal para proceder al pago, pero este procedimiento era el anterior, ahora utilizando este método de pasar los datos al `.load` cómo generas el duplicado de esos campos específicos  cuando por ejemplo existen dos productos distintos añadidos al carrito de la compra o más producto [ejemplo genera los siguientes datos](https://ideone.com/xeibb0)

Comment: @J.Doe me faltaría saber de dónde sale `$num` y el resto de los valores que quieres pasar. ¿El formulario se manda a sí mismo? No me termina de quedar claro cómo se generan esos campos del formulario.

Comment: Creó que  vamos a dejar el tema ahí... Ya lo importante me has enseñado en la respuesta, esa variable lo que hace es contar el total de filas el total de resultados por ejemplo si tengo añadido 2 productos al carrito e imprimo esa variable eso me creaba un resultado como este https://ideone.com/xeibb0 esto los puedes verificar y comprobar con mi antiguo procedimiento de mi pregunta sobre el archivo pay_paypal.php pero como dije esa era el antiguo procedimiento donde me toco tener que añadir todos los datos y los códigos del cartel.php a esa plantilla pero como dije para evitar

Comment: Eso pregunté cómo enviar las variables por medio del .load recuerdas pero si ya no logro hacer entender dejemos el tema ahí como dije lo más importante ya lo has mencionado :)